# Conditional storage class dependent upon template parameter

Tags: c++, type-traits, storage-class-specifier

The following doesn't appear to be valid c++ (`-std=c++2a`). I want to change the storage class of `var` based on the template parameter `b`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <bool b>
void f() {
  typename std::conditional<b, static int, int>::type var;
}
```

Comment: Why? What is the actual problem you need to solve? Why do you think you need something like this?

Comment: `f` here is a simplified representation of a function which is invoked under two regimes of operation: one allocates very little and is called in a tight loop, the other allocates a lot and is called seldomly. I want the first to be static, the second to deallocate after each call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The storage class specifier is part of the object's [declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations) and is not part of the object's type.

Hence it can't be used where a type is expected.

Expanding on cigien's specialization proposal, you can wrap the variable into a helper container class.

```
template<bool b> struct A;

template<> struct A<true> {
    inline static int var = 0;
};

template<> struct A<false> {
    int var = 0;
};

template <bool b>
void f() {
    A<b> a;
    int& var = a.var;
    do_something_with(var);
}
```

Beware that the semantics in doing this are quite different - one is created in automatic storage for every invocation, the other is initialized once and shared between invocations. In a threaded environment the former is safe, the latter isn't, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could provide full specializations of `f`, like this:

```
template <bool b> void f();

template <> void f<true>()
{
  static int var;
}

template <> void f<false>()
{
  int var;
}
```

This should have the same effect as you are trying to achieve.